# What's the difference between link-layer and e.g. transport-layer reliability?

Tags: networking, tcp, routes

I have googled this and been sent to questions on stackoverflow a couple of times, but I am still not convinced. They simply say that link-layer reliability concerns itself with single hop, and higher layer reliablity (for instance transport layer reliability) concerns itself with end-to-end reliability.

But won't the sum of all reliable single hops be the same as end-to-end reliablity? So in the end, what's really the difference?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sliding Window at Transport and Data-Link layers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324460/sliding-window-at-transport-and-data-link-layers)

Comment: The question I linked to deals with sliding window and flow control in addition to error control, but it should contain the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Link layer reliability provides reliable delivery over a link. However, packet can still be dropped in router for a limited buffer size. Therefore, even all links provide reliable service, it doesn't guarantee an end-to-end reliability.